# PostgreSQL function string_agg in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

In PostgreSQL, **string_agg(column, separator)** allows to aggregate some Strings. I try to use it with JPA but it is not a JPA standard function.

Note : This is **not** the equivalent of **CriteriaBuilder#concat()**.

So, I tried to tell JPA that this function exists, like this :

```
public class StringAgg extends ParameterizedFunctionExpression<String> implements Serializable {

  public static final String NAME = "string_agg";

  @Override
  public boolean isAggregation() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isStandardJpaFunction() {
    return false;
  }

  public StringAgg(CriteriaBuilderImpl criteriaBuilder, Expression<String> expression, String separator) {
    super(criteriaBuilder, String.class, NAME, expression, new LiteralExpression(criteriaBuilder, separator));
  }
}
```

Then :

```
Expression<String> exprStr = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
cb.construct(MyClass.class, 
             myClass.get(MyClass_.name),
             myClass.get(MyClass_.surname),
             new StringAgg(cb, exprStr, "/"));
```

Problem, **I get a NullPointerException** !

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1028) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2279) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2145) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.0.Beta3.jar:4.3.0.Beta3]
```

The debugger shows that the last `Selection` of `cb.construct()` (`new StringAgg(cb, exprStr, "/")`) is ignored. As a consequence, the searched constructor is `MyClass(String,String)` instead of `MyClass(String, String, String)`.

Is there something wrong in the implementation of StringAgg? Did someone already tried to use string_agg in JPA?

**Solution** (thanks to vzamanillo)

Extend the dialect :

```
public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect{

  public PGDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction("string_agg", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)"));
  }
}
```

Use it in **persistence.xml**

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="path.to.PGDialect"/>
```

Then use **CriteriaBuilder#function()** :

```
Expression<String> exprStr = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
cb.construct(MyClass.class, 
             myClass.get(MyClass_.name),
             myClass.get(MyClass_.surname),
             cb.function( "string_agg", myColPath, cb.literal("delimiter" )));
```

To ease it, I created a helper method :

```
public static Expression<String> strAgg(CriteriaBuilder cb, Expression<String> expression, String delimiter) {
  return cb.function( "string_agg", String.class, expression, cb.literal(delimiter));
}
```

So the code becomes :

```
Expression<String> exprStr = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
cb.construct(MyClass.class, 
             myClass.get(MyClass_.name),
             myClass.get(MyClass_.surname),
             strAgg(cb, myColPath, "delimiter"));
```

Comment: FUNCTION is a JPA (2.1) standard function. Perhaps use that

Comment: Why don't you use the normal constructor of a class, the equivalent of `SELECT new com.me.Entity(path1, path2)...` in JPQL? (PS: +1 as I learned something new)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe this helps you,

you can invoke database functions in a JPA Criteria Query.

The CriteriaBuilder Interface has a "[function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...%29)" method.

```
<T> Expression<T> function(String name,
                         Class<T> type,
                         Expression<?>... args)

Create an expression for the execution of a database function.

Parameters:
    name - function name
    type - expected result type
    args - function arguments
Returns:
    expression
```

Then you can try creating a CriteriaBuilder helper class to get a plain criteria Expression that you can use as usual in our criteria query

```
public abstract class CriteriaBuilderHelper {

    private static final String PG_STRING_AGG  = "string_agg";

    /**
    * @param cb the CriteriaBuilder to use
    * @param toJoin the string to join
    * @param delimiter the string to use
    * @return Expression<String>
    */
    public static Expression functionStringAgg(CriteriaBuilder cb, String toJoin, String delimiter) {
        return cb.function(PG_STRING_AGG, 
            String.class,
            cb.literal(toJoin),
            cb.literal(delimiter))
        );
    }
}
```

or you can use a custom dialect to register a new function

```
public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect{

    public PGDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("string_agg", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

and use it in your CriteriaBuilder as a normal function

```
Expression<String> functionStringAgg = cb.function( "string_agg", String.class, 
                                cb.parameter(String.class, "toJoin" ), 
                                cb.parameter(String.class, "delimiter"));
```

after all don't forget to set the parameter values to the your CriteriaQuery

```
setParameter( "toJoin", toJoin);
setParameter( "delimiter", delimiter);
```

Comment: You rock :) The first solution did not work : I ended up with the same problem. My code did almost the same. But registering the function via a new Dialect worked like a charm.

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle can you please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218784/string-agg-with-criteria-builder issue

Comment: @vzamanillo can you please help on stackoverflow.com/questions/55218784/… issue

Comment: I got this error 

`
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (string_agg)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'string_agg' {originalText=string_agg}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=empId, expectedType=null}
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=delimiter, expectedType=null}
`

Comment: It's 2023 but no modern solution to this except the custom dialect 

Answer (score 2):

I did it using the same structure, but in an easy way:

Modified the persistence file:

```
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">es.gmrcanarias.saga.utiles.PGDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
...
        </props>
    </property>
```

Then registerede the function:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {

   public PGDialect() {
       super();
      registerFunction("string_agg", new  
       SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)"));
   }
}
```

Then added the query:

```
    Join<Razon, Incidenc> subquery;
    ....
    Expression<String> functionStringAgg = criteriaBuilder.function("string_agg", 
        String.class,
        subquery.get(CODIGO), 
        criteriaBuilder.literal(", "));
...
    subqueryList.select(functionStringAgg);
```

Answer (score 1):

One detail for PGDialect:
You can add the 3rd argument for using ORDER BY

```
public class PGDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {


     public PGDialect() {
         super();
         this.registerFunction("string_agg", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2)") );
         this.registerFunction("string_agg", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "string_agg(?1, ?2 ORDER BY ?3 )") );
     }
 }
```

HQL Query usage

```
 "SELECT string_agg(f.name, '; ', f.name) FROM Foo as f "
```